# is there a way to do multi-step form without conditionally rendering each step in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js

I'm trying to create a multi-step form in NextJS.Now i'm just conditionally render each step with a state as step number.is there an another better way to do this?

```
const [showStep, setshowStep] = useState<number>(1);
 function RenderStep() {
   switch (showStep) {
     case 1:
       return <StepOne setStep={setshowStep} />;
     case 2:
       return <StepTwo setStep={setshowStep}/>;
     case 3:
       return <StepThree setStep={setshowStep}/>;
     case 4:
       return <StepFour setStep={setshowStep}/>;
     default:
       return <StepOne setStep={setshowStep} />;
   }
 }
 return (
   <div>
     <Page>
       <Link href="/campaigns">back</Link>
       <RenderStep />
     </Page>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: What about use each step as different subpage in `pages` folder? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simple way would have to create a `<Step>` component that contains your step content like this:

```
import {PropsWithChildren} from "react";

interface StepProps {
  value: number;
  index: number;
}

const Step = (props: PropsWithChildren<StepProps>): JSX.Element | null => {
  const {children, index, value} = props;
  return index === value ? <>{children}</> : null;
}
```

Which would allow you afterwards to have something like

```
<Step index={0} value={showStep}>
// your step 0 content
</Step>
<Step index={1} value={showStep}>
// your step 1 content
</Step>
```

and so on.